# How to solve multiple databases in one edmx for ASP.net MVC?

Tags: model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-4, edmx, ado.net-entity-data-model, multiple-databases

After I searched around on Google and Stackoverflow, I understand that I need to ask because I'm newbie about MVC.

My question is How to use multiple databases on edmx?

I think if I can put entity from different databases on same edmx, MVC can generate dropdownlist on View. But I have no idea about this and don't know how to solve.

Rgds

Answer (score 1):

It might be possible if you can first setup my database synonyms. Check this blog post for how it works. http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/05/22/tricking-ef-to-span-multiple-databases/