# Multiple Databases in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-mvc-4, linq-to-entities, ado.net-entity-data-model

I'm very first experience in ASP.NET MVC and after I read through a few articles I decided I try my new project with MVC.

And I used ADO.net entity data model and I created Create/ Delete/ Details/ Edit/ Index. It works fine.
So I plan to improve in user interface because some of the fields are comes from another databases such as HR Database, etc... for employee information.

for e.g : to choose Employee's Name on my form, I have to use DropDownList and that data comes from another database, HR as I mentioned in above. I have no idea how to access difference database in one model and here I asked [How to solve multiple databases in one edmx for ASP.net MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16706122/how-to-solve-multiple-databases-in-one-edmx-for-asp-net-mvc)

However I tried to create one more model for the other database and try to join with Linq.

```
//
    // GET: /ARS/

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var employee = new List<EMPLOYEE>(chr.EMPLOYEEs);
        var reqform = new List<RequestForm>(ars.RequestForms.Include(r => r.Genre));

        var requestforms = from r in reqform
                           join e in employee on r.PrjDeptMgr equals e.EmployeeID
                           select new
                             {
                                 r.FormID,
                                 r.GenreID,
                                 r.JobNo,
                                 r.Description,
                                 r.StartDate,
                                 r.EndDate,
                                 r.PrjDeptMgr,
                                 r.IsAgreed,
                                 r.Genre
                             };

        //var requestforms = ars.RequestForms.Include(r => r.Genre);
        return View(requestforms.ToList());
    }
```

But I got this error

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[<>f__AnonymousType2`9[System.Int32,System.Int32,System.String,System.String,System.DateTime,System.DateTime,System.String,System.Boolean,Access_Request_System.Models.Genre]]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Access_Request_System.Models.RequestForm]'.

Really no idea for this case... Please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your view file requires `IEnumerable<RequestForm>`, but the type you're passing does not match the required type (it's `anonymous`).

Try the following changes.

```
List<RequestForm> requestforms = (from r in reqform
                       join e in employee on r.PrjDeptMgr equals e.EmployeeID
                       select new RequestForm
                         {
                             FormID = r.FormID,
                             Genre = r.GenreID,
                             JobNo = r.JobNo,
                             Description = r.Description,
                             StartDate = r.StartDate,
                             EndDate = r.EndDate,
                             PrjDeptMgr = r.PrjDeptMgr,
                             IsAgreed = r.IsAgreed,
                             Genre = r.Genre
                         }).ToList();

return View(requestForms);
```

Comment: so you mean that I need to use ViewModel, right?
If It is so, How do I use dropdownlist in EditTemplate
for e.g : want to use ddl for PrjDeptMgr and bind form another db

and thanks for your answer...

Comment: The value you're passing to the view using `View()` is your view model. You're view model type as specified in the view file is OK. It's the value you're passing to it (`List<RequestForm>`) that was incorrect. The drop down list will need to be populated somehow (that's up to you). I'm not aware of the edit template supporting dropdown lists AFAIK.